# Generating points along the line at equal intervals excluding vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, qgis-processing, point-creation

I want to generate points along a line at equal intervals but the final point layer should not contain the vertices points. It should only contain points at specified intervals.

Tools in QGIS such as "Points Along Line" or "Points along Geometry" will include points at the vertices of the line layer.

Comment: Can you not generate points along the line then filter out and delete the begin and end points?

Comment: Sir, may you please explain a little bit more on how to filter the vertices points from the all points generated. @LeighBettenay. My line is a complex one with lot of vertices spaced irregularly. So can't find a method to filter even from the attribute table.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25542/splitting-lines-at-a-specified-distance suggests to use v.to.points https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.to.points.html to place points at an defined interval along a line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tool ["Points along geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry), which has the option to offset the start and end points by a specified distance.

In the following example, the distance is specified at a regular interval of 1000 meters. The same distance was used in the start and end offset to exclude the start and end points.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a [Virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer` with the formula:

```sql
select Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points(geometry, 50)
from "Simplified"
```

Replace `"Simplified"` with the name of your line layer, and 50 with your desired point interval. It will create a point every 50 m measured along each line.

The output will be a multipoint layer. Convert it to singleparts using ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts):

[image]